# Node JS Cursor with different collection data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Here, I have a sample code where getting data from one collection and put it into cursor and again from another collection getting data in that the data which I am pushing that I want to use in below cursor.How to use that.I am getting blank[] response.

```
{
    let f1= [];
                let f2 = [];
                let f3 = [];
         var cursor = collection.find({'timestamp':{"$gte":queryObject.fromdate,"$lt" : queryObject.todate}}).sort({"timestamp":1});

         var collectionname  = db.collection("col2");
         collectionname.find({}).each(function(err, doc) {
                for(let i in doc.Data)
                {
                    for(let j in doc.Data[i].position)
                    {
                        for(let k in doc.Data[i].position[j].status)
                    {
                        f1.push(doc.Data[i].position[j].pcode);
                        f2.push(doc.Data[i].position[j].status[k].value);
                        f3.push(doc.Data[i].position[j].status[k].code);                 
         cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
                if(doc!=null){
                    if(index==0){
                    }
                    var temp = {};
                    var obj = doc.data[0];  
                    var Count = 0;
                    for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                        if(obj[temp[i]]!=undefined){
                        if(obj[temp[i]]==f2 && temp[i]==f1){
                        temp[temp[i]] = f3;
                        temp.timestamp = obj.timestamp;
                        Count++;
                        }
                        else{
                                temp[temp[i]] = obj[temp[i]];
                                Count++;
                                temp.timestamp = obj.timestamp;
                        }           
                        }   
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                        res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  });
                var resultData = {"data":resultset,"success":true};
                res.write(JSON.stringify(resultData));
                  res.end();    
                }
        }); 

    }}} 

     });
}
```

Edit: Data is coming from col2 and now i want to match with col1 in condition ,able to iterate the col1 temp but from col2 f1,f2,f3 data not able to iterate it is always coming first.
How to archive that.Please help with same.
Sample json for Col2:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d47780d882f82f656c7978"),
    "code" : "1",
    "Data" : [
        {
            "pcode" : "AA",
            "Name" : "x",
        },
        {
            "pcode" : "BB",
            "Name" : "y",
            "position" : [
                {
                    "pcode" : "BB",
                    "position" : "15",
                    "status" : [
                        {
                            "code" : "0",
                            "value" : "OFF"
                        },
                        {
                            "code" : "1",
                            "value" : "ON"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "pcode" : "CC",
                    "position" : "14",
                    "status" : [
                        {
                            "code" : "0",
                            "value" : "YES"
                        },
                        {
                            "code" : "1",
                            "value" : "NO"
                        }
                    ]
                },
    ],
    "type" : "1122",

}
```

And Sample json for Col1:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9c3b504fd78e675e619d61"),
    "data" : [
        {
            "BB" : "OFF",
            "CC" : "YES",
            "type" : "1122"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample document and your expected output from the desired operation?

Comment: Please change `obj[temp[i]]!=undefined` to `typeof obj[temp[i]] !== 'undefined'`

Comment: ok,But how to compare array in condition ?

Comment: above to cursor,array is not iterating ? How to do that?

Comment: @chridam I have update the question with sample json,Please help with same.

Comment: Thanks for adding sample data from both collections, can you also add your expected output?

Comment: expected output is like if the obj[temp[i]]==f2 && temp[i]==f1 condition gets true then assing temp[temp[i]] = f3 and according to that will graph trend.

Comment: I don't think you got what I meant, wanted to see the final desired output so that I can help you come up with the appropriate query by deducing the correct aggregate pipeline that transforms the given output to the desired json final result i.e. `pipeline(input) => output`

Comment: In other words, what do you expect `resultset` to be given those input sample data?

Comment: if i am putting console here
f1.push(doc.Data[i].position[j].pcode);
                        f2.push(doc.Data[i].position[j].status[k].value);
                        f3.push(doc.Data[i].position[j].status[k].code); 
i m getting each value twice.